MacPorts 2.10.0 broken after Sonoma update 14.6.1 (M2 Max)
After migrating to MacPorts 2.10.0 via
$ sudo port selfupdating
Password:
--->  Updating MacPorts base sources using rsync
MacPorts base version 2.9.3 installed,
MacPorts base version 2.10.0 downloaded.
--->  Updating the ports tree
--->  MacPorts base is outdated, installing new version 2.10.0
Installing new MacPorts release in /opt/local as root:wheel; permissions 0775

Error: Error installing new MacPorts base: command execution failed
Please run `port -v selfupdate' for details.
Error: /opt/local/bin/port: port selfupdate failed: Error installing new MacPorts base: command execution failed 

I tried sudo port migrate together with the recommended change to the new URL in sources.conf.
A following selfupdate produced the output
$ sudo port selfupdate
--->  Checking for newer releases of MacPorts
MacPorts base version 2.10.0 installed,
MacPorts base version 2.10.0 available.
--->  MacPorts base is already the latest version
--->  Updating the ports tree
Error: updating PortIndex for rsync://rsync.macports.org/macports/release/tarballs/ports.tar failed

The ports tree has been updated.

29 ports are outdated. Run 'port outdated' for details.
To upgrade your installed ports, you should run
  port upgrade outdated


Unfortunately, it seems that now MacPorts is broken:
$ sudo port outdated
Error: Current platform "darwin 23" does not match expected platform "darwin 23"
Error: Please run 'sudo port migrate' or follow the migration instructions: https://trac.macports.org/wiki/Migration
OS platform mismatch
    while executing
"mportinit ui_options global_options global_variations"
Error: /opt/local/bin/port: Failed to initialize MacPorts, OS platform mismatch

Any help is highly appreciated.

Can you make a list of installed software/ports with port installed? Here a link to the MacPorts guide- https://guide.macports.org/

@fd0: No not possible anymore because MacPorts is not working anymore. port installed produces same error as outdated.

And when you specified the verbose flag, what did selfupdate tell you was wrong?  All you show is other things besides the recommended.

I wonder also what would happen if you installed the appropriately versioned .pkg, versus letting it try to upgrade itself.  After making the appropriate backup, of course.

The key to the issue is in the error message- OS platform mismatch. Did you enable rosetta ?

There's a similar thread on macports-devel where it turned out that the user was running Terminal.app under Rosetta and trying to update an ARM MacPorts install.  Good catch!

Following the corresponding thread at MacPorts and the hints in the comments I found out with
lipo -info /opt/local/libexec/macports/bin/tclsh8.6

that my installation is only x86_64 (without arm64).
According to MacPorts developers one should firstly install a universal version of MacPorts base. For Sonoma 14 the .pkg installer can be found here. This results in a universal MacPorts base (version 2.10.1). Depending on the number of installed ports, MacPorts updates certain dependencies, which takes some time, but eventually, everything runs as expected.

Let's start with a list of ports installed. The following command will produce a list-
 sqlite3 /opt/local/var/macports/registry/registry.db \
     'select name,  version, revision,  
      state, os_platform, os_major, archs, date from ports' |      
 sort |
  awk -F'|' '{ if ( $4 == "installed") {act="(active)"} else  {act=""} } 
 { cmd = "date -r" $8 " +%Y-%m-%dT%T%z"; cmd | getline mydate; close(cmd) }

 { printf ("%s @%s_%s %s platform=%s %s archs=%s date=%s\n",
 $1, $2, $3, act,$5, $6, $7, mydate)
 }'

I think reinstall is your only option.
